# How to insert a array values in php to database of sql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am using this function and I am unable to insert the data in table. Please help me out if there is anything wrong.
My data is like below:-

```
Array

    (
        [0] => Oxit_zGvsfA
        [1] => ABfJ8CD72ng
        [2] => hK4LFM_TFrk
        [3] => AwBwgNa9WhQ
        [4] => iBxjDs8u6Ac
        [5] => S4FbQ6GWSjs
        [6] => Qoh2L9o4EAI
        [7] => 5plSoJHecA8
        [8] => KeglR7c1dCU
        [9] => FQiZrk3N_uo
        [10] => biHIFOjQyks
        [11] => _Mc4hzi-Vs8
        [12] => ueJUEL_sEIA
        [13] => jt86_mRfCds
        [14] => xmwNbW1m31I
        [15] => K1B7V4ZWcEU
        [16] => zHdHrWzDQh8
        [17] => yDF1hVZdezA
        [18] => C4IVGN55eBk
        [19] => uiY_FHWvZcg
        [20] => GYZXT2_EuJY
        [21] => _oCUTn9ThNc
        [22] => fPG6B5m-P1U
        [23] => Qd5OhbWmohg
        [24] => hwFTQibLBG8
        [25] => Ijvkn_dl6yw
        [26] => jCMmqlsZ-OY
        [27] => ymFKFy7Xs40
        [28] => cpBWT0H6Ihw
        [29] => ThW8jrf64bI
        [30] => -JjOpRDIyqY
    )
```

My code to insert the data tin table:-

```
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($videos); $i++)
{
    $ip= $videos[$i];
    echo $ip;
    echo "</br>";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO hindisongs (S.No) VALUES ('$ip')";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    if($query)
    {
       echo 'data inserted sucessfully';
    }

}
```

You can see that I am converting the array value into string and then I want to insert the data into the string or if any other solution is present, tell me.

In my database, I can see that:

```
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0023 seconds.)
```

Comment: `S.No` as a column name needs to be in backticks, that should be erring. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html You also should parameterize the query.

Comment: If you're not going to parameterise the query, then you only need one insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid doing, 'Query in Loop'.
Try something like this:

```
$vals = '';
foreach($videos as $ip){
    $vals .= "('$ip'),";
}

if(!empty($vals)) {
    $vals = rtrim($vals, ',');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `hindisongs` (`S.No`) VALUES $vals;";
    if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
      echo('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$error = array();
foreach($videos as $ip){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO hindisongs (S.No) VALUES ('$ip')";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
         $error[] = $ip;
    }
}

var_dump($error);
```

Try like this and you will get to know which indexes have issue.